# looping arrays in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just want to check that I'm doing this right. I have an array of objects in my Vuex store. I am wanting to loop over that array, and for each object, render a component. The array in question is `projects`.

The loop looks like this:

```html
<project-item v-for="project in projects" v-bind:project="project" :key="project.id"></project-item>
```

I get what I expect to see rendered to screen, but just want to make sure I'm doing it the accepted way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general syntax for looping through an array:

```
<my-component
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  v-bind:item="item"
  v-bind:index="index"
  v-bind:key="item.id"></my-component>
```

So, you are doing it right. See [list reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) for more details.